# Managing dates when they're overlapping

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, overlapping

How to write a procedure so that when adding a new insert, rows are added appropriately?

Let's say i have a table:

```
create table test_table
(
code varchar2(10) not null,
type varchar2(50) not null,
start_date date not null,
end_date date not null,
parameter number
);
```

**1. First test case:**

In table we have:

```
insert into test_table values ('CODE', 'a', to_date('01.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'),  to_date('10.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'), 1);
```

*[2021-01-01 - 2021-01-10] type = "a" parameter = 1*

and when we want to insert:

```
insert into test_table values ('CODE', 'a', to_date('01.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'),  to_date('20.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'), 1)
```

*[2021-01-11 - 2021-01-20] type = "a" parameter = 1*

```
*Result should be:
2021-01-01 - 2021-01-20 type = "a" parameter = 1*
```

---

**2. Second test case:**

In table we have:

```
insert into test_table values ('CODE', 'a', to_date('01.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'),  to_date('10.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'), 1)
```

[2021-01-01 - 2021-01-10] type = "a" parameter = 1

and when we want to insert:

```
insert into test_table values ('CODE', 'a', to_date('06.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'),  to_date('20.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'), 2)
```

[2021-01-06 - 2021-01-20] type = "a" parameter = 2

```
*in result we should have:
[2021-01-01 - 2021-01-05] type = "a" parameter = 1
[2021-01-06 - 2021-01-20] type = "a" parameter = 2*
```

---

**3. Third test case:**

In table we have:

```
insert into test_table values ('CODE', 'a', to_date('01.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'),  to_date('10.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'), 1)
```

[2021-01-01 - 2021-01-20] type = "a" parameter = 1

and when we want to insert:

```
insert into test_table values ('CODE', 'a', to_date('06.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'),  to_date('15.01.2021', 'DD,MM,YYYY'), 2)
```

*[2021-01-06 - 2021-01-15] type = "a" parameter = 2*

```
*in result we should have:
[2021-01-01 - 2021-01-05] type = "a" parameter = 1
[2021-01-06 - 2021-01-15] type = "a" parameter = 2
[2021-01-16 - 2021-01-20] type = "a" parameter = 1*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a new date range that is completely contained in the middle of an existing date range then you need to: `INSERT` of the new range; `UPDATE` the existing range to the portion of that range before the new range; and `INSERT` a new range for the portion of the existing range after the new range. So you need a total of 3 changes.

Similarly, when you insert a new date range that completely contains an existing range then you need to: `INSERT` the new range; and `DELETE` the existing range (or do a single `UPDATE` statement).

You can use a single `MERGE` statement for all of these actions:

```sql
MERGE INTO test_table dst
USING (
  WITH new_data (code, type, start_date, end_date, parameter) AS (
    SELECT 'CODE2', 'a', DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-20', 2 FROM DUAL
  )
  SELECT NULL AS rid,
         n.*,
         0 AS status -- Insert
  FROM   new_data n
  UNION ALL
  -- Existing rows overlapping before
  SELECT t.ROWID,
         t.code,
         t.type,
         t.start_date,
         n.start_date - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         t.parameter,
         1 -- Update overlap before
  FROM   test_table t
         INNER JOIN new_data n
         ON (   t.start_date <= n.start_date
            AND t.end_date   >= n.start_date)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.ROWID,
         t.code,
         t.type,
         n.end_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         t.end_date,
         t.parameter,
         CASE
         WHEN n.start_date <= t.end_date   AND t.end_date <= n.end_date
         THEN 2 -- Delete
         WHEN t.start_date < n.start_date  AND n.end_date <  t.end_date
         THEN 0 -- Insert overlap afterwards
         ELSE 1 -- Update overlap afterwards
         END
  FROM   test_table t
         INNER JOIN new_data n
         ON (   t.start_date <= n.end_date
            AND t.end_date   >= n.start_date)
  WHERE  NOT (t.start_date <= n.start_date AND t.end_date <= n.end_date)
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID AND status > 0)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    code       = src.code,
         start_date = src.start_date,
         end_date   = src.end_date
  DELETE
  WHERE status = 2
  OR    src.start_date > src.end_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (code, type, start_date, end_date, parameter)
  VALUES (src.code, src.type, src.start_date, src.end_date, src.parameter);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfc395cd5f9e9fdd9b35153e4cd01701)*

Comment: I was thinking about using merge but i really dont know how to make all changes in one merge. One question: how should i modyfiy code so if i add:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f9f166c1c3545074bea1f8b0b75159d7

i would have one row in result? i mean 1.01.2021 - 20.01.2021

Comment: @andrea_sottolamontagna That appears to be an entirely different question that does not match the expected results in this question; I suggest you [ask it as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and clarify, in that new question, what you expect the behaviour to be if the `code`/`type`/`parameter` values are different in the adjacent ranges.